# PHP: How to parse Lilypond file?

Tags: php, grammar, lilypond

I need to extract the Score part from a Lilypond file ([example .ly file here)](https://github.com/strch/public-domain-season-songs/blob/master/alle_jahre_wieder.ly) with separated voices.

My idea is to read the [Lilypond grammar](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/contributor/lilypond-grammar) from  a file and create a PHP parser using the [PHP builtin features for parsers.](https://www.php.net/manual/de/parle.examples.parser.php)

My question is how to read the Lilypond grammar?

I did not find a standard EBNF grammar source for Lilypond. And the [Lilypond parser written in BIson on Github](https://github.com/lilypond/lilypond/blob/483292eb80da0869d22cd773eb480c662a499e89/lily/parser.yy) does not help much.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider using the [Abjad](https://abjad.github.io/) package for Python? It does have a quite advanced parser from what I can understand (check the class `LilyPondParser`, which is described in the Abjad API in the link above). Writing a parser yourself would be quite a task, as Josiah from Abjad [describes](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/music21list/50vR0VYQB4E/6qfw7FTKEvcJ).

Comment: @gilbertohasnofb: I don't want to go down to notes, just extract voices in ly-format. That's enough. I'll recombine them later e.g. with different pitches, different arrangements. So, I don't need a full ly-file parser, just a little bit of it.