# PHP: writing a parser for Lilypond file format

Tags: php, parsing, lilypond

Lilypond is a tool for writing sheet music. The Lilypond file format .ly describes the music to be engraved.

I need to extract the `\score` part and various `\header` information (fully expanded).

Since PHP is my primary programming language I want to go with PHP. The PHP parser must run in a Docker file.

Here are the basics:

- [A Lilypond sample file](https://github.com/cscott/LiveMusic/blob/05c06b210bc1738746a805ad2ae89eaf81b0fdc0/red-haired-boy-a.ly)
- [The Lilypond grammar (with terminals and non-terminals)](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/contributor/lilypond-grammar)

How to build a parser for the Lilypond language in PHP?

I tried to so far:

- writing my own Parser and Lexer but stopped because things got complex very fast
- starting to use the [PHP PECL Parle](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.parle.php) (Parser & Lexer): This is not installable using composer nor installable in a Docker PHP container since there is only a beta version of Parle

Comment: The last Parle release 0.8.1 **is** in stability beta and you can't hope a better release actually. [link](https://pecl.php.net/package/parle)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I don't need a stable package. Would also go with a beta package. But how to install beta packages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: How to parse Lilypond file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881971/php-how-to-parse-lilypond-file)

Comment: No, @gilbertohasnofb, but only because that original question by the same questioner hasn’t been answered either (as of writing).